# Are there any tools better than White for WPF automation test?

Tags: wpf, automated-tests

I found the project [White](http://white.codeplex.com) in codeplex and [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). However I was wondering if there are better tools for WPF automation.

Comment: What do you want to test? Did you use an architecture pattern, e.g. MVVM?

Comment: Snoop isn't an automation tool it's a spy replacement for wpf applications.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Snoop is only a spy tool, however a spy tool is required for automation testing.

Comment: UISpy and [Visual UIA Verify](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/) are also popular spy tool choices when creating Coded UI Tests for your WPF apps.

Comment: Both links are dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be you should learn the 'base' of all above systems - its [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). It's really not that hard to learn and get used to. It's sometime not trivial (like finding or setting SelectedItem in ComboBox for example) but actually all above system it's mostly a wrappers around UI Automation that is already build-in into .NET.

Comment: Hi Jasper, I already notice that as well. I just thought there must be a framework that can help to abstract some things and to make it easier writing integration tests.

Comment: Hi Jasper, I tried with UI Automation to write a proof of concept and it is really easy. I don't know why do we need a framework for doing that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Hadi mentioned, [Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools) will help you with record/playback and lots of other features.

That said, since you're interested in something to tie in to the various DSL-ish tools, then please have a look at our [free testing framework](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx). You can use it to write powerful, code-based tests for WPF as well as browser-based tests.

The testing framework also has a fee-based support system if you are looking for great technical support during your project.

Comment: It seems that the free testing framework from telerik is a good option because it allows recording or coding from automated tests. Although the support package is not free I am going to try it.

Comment: Diego: Please be clear! The free framework is a coded-only solution. The recorder is not part of that toolset.

Comment: Hi Jim, your are right, code only is free, that is great!. What I mean is that the Support Package (support inquiries answered in 24 hours) must be paid, one need to buy a License for one Year.

Answer (score 1):

Recording features are nice but when it comes to creating a maintainable and extensible UI tests, you inevitable end up writing them by your own. I would recommend sticking to White if this is the case and use Coded UI with the built-in recorder if you have only a couple of tests.

Here I compare the two frameworks in more detail: [Coded UI vs White](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/09/22/coded-ui-vs-white/)

Answer (score 0):

There are other tools, mostly commercial. Take a look at [Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/wpf-testing.aspx) from Telerik and then there's the [CodedUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) that comes with Visual Studio Ultimate versions.

Comment: Test Studio and CodeUI are recording oriented and that is something that I would not like, because I want to use it in an agile delopment. It means that the UI will change because requirements can change and updating generated code brings some problems. I am looking something where I can influence how the tests are written (in code) with an easily Domain Specific Language or something like that.

Comment: It is still possible to use tools like SpecFlow and CodedUI. Read http://rburnham.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/bdd-ui-automation-with-specflow-and-coded-ui-tests or http://scrumdod.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-integrate-specflow-and-coded-ui.html although I agree with CodedUI being brittle.